# How do I add multiple fields in the same row in SQL (ms Access)?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vba

I spent two days on this and I still can't seem to solve it.

This is my current code in VBA that works, but for one field only. I tried to modify it to make it work for multiple fields but failed in doing so.

```
Dim SQL as String

SQL = "INSERT INTO tblProviders (Provider) " _
& "VALUES(" _
& "'" & Me!txtProvider & "' ) "

DoCmd.RunSQL
```

Where tblProviders is my table of choice, Provider is my field and txtProvider is where the user inserts the information.

If I do the following I get errors:

```
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "INSERT INTO tblProviders (Provider, Adress) VALUES (" & Me.txtProvider & "," & Me.txtAdress & ")"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

The following doesn't work either as it just makes 2 new rows instead of adding them all to the same row:

```
Dim SQL1 as String

SQL1 = "INSERT INTO tblProviders (Provider) " _
& "VALUES(" _
& "'" & Me!txtProvider & "' ) "

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL1

Dim SQL as String

SQL2 = "INSERT INTO tblProviders (Provider) " _
& "VALUES(" _
& "'" & Me!txtAdres & "' ) "

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL2
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: I get a parameter window and no matter what I insert it won't get pushed to my table, even though it asks me if it can append a row.

Comment: You said you are getting errors? What are the errors?

Comment: Compile error: Syntax error

Comment: Can you share the error here... It would be a lot helpful...

Comment: That's all it says unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build your string, you need to plan for the quotes in the final SQL statement. Try this:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO tblProviders (Provider, Adress) VALUES ('" & _
         Me.txtProvider & "', '" & Me.txtAdress & "')"  
'print the result for control
debug.Print SQL
```

I use a single quote `'` within the double quotes `"`, like this `"'Hi'"`.
One can also double the inside double quotes, like this `"""Hi"""` , but I find it unreadable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, but that gives me green text like in commenting http://postimg.org/image/pgyw0fvzn/

Comment: I'm getting Run-time error 3075: Syntaxt error (missing operator) in query expression)

Comment: Fixed at end of 1st line